# I don't know why My Final Render is all black

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

I make an emission shader and a principled shader make all with extrude and model it.

I pressed render to watch the final result but is all black.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate. They should be removed.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth there is no reason to remove duplicates (unless is the same user asking the same question repeatedly). Duplicates are not a bad thing at all, marking a question as a duplicate just means that there are already answers in some other page, so there is no need to write another. Duplicates might help others to find the information they need.  Read: [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates)